# I owe rent for a month and my landord is threatening me to move my stuff out of the house

Tags: rental-property, rent

This is Covid19 pandemic time and I understand that it is a tough time for everyone.

I'm living in a rented single room in a shared-house with a verbal agreement (No on-paper lease) in MA, US. As per the verbal agreement, I'm supposed to pay the rent at the start of every month. Also, there is a 1-month deposit which I had already paid. Also, I'm not sure if my landlord is renting the place legally or illegally.

Only, this month (May 2020), I requested him to pay the rent of May & June together by *June 15th*. Also, I haven't been staying at my house since more than 2 month. But, he threatens me to pay rent of May within a couple of days or he will ask someone to put my personal belongings from my room to somewhere outside the house in my absence and without my permission.

Q. Can he legally do that without me giving him permission and in my absence?

Any solution or recommendation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would be far better off seeking advice from a lawyer than from random people on a personal finance Q&A site.

Comment: Why would you move in somewhere with strangers with no written agreement?

Comment: You haven't been there in months and you haven't paid the rent for a month... He might be able to claim you abandoned the place, I've signed leases which said they'd consider properties abandoned much faster than two months. You could try to bluff him and say it's illegal and you'll sue, but personally I wouldn't risk it if you can avoid it.

Comment: @Victor Sorry for confusion. I did pay for the other previous months rent though. I have my belongings there and I'm planning to continuing stay. Temporarily, I'm staying with my cousins because of pandemic as I don't want to be near my roomates.

Comment: Is the landlord the owner of the property. Or are you renting a room from somebody that is renting the whole  house from the owner?

Comment: landlord is the owner and he doesn't live in the same house though

Comment: @Dhruvil21_04 - it still doesn't answer the question of why you would move in somewhere with strangers with no written agreement and just a verbal agreement? You were just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Victor Actually one of friend used to live here. He left after I came to this house.

Comment: @Dhruvil21_04 - you don't seem to understand what I am saying - you are now in trouble because you did not have what you could do and could not do written and signed by both parties!

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain well enough. From next time, I will take care to have a written agreement. But, any solution you would like to recommend for now?

Answer (score 3):

Due to COVID-19 many places have halted evictions. In some places the emergency laws still may have required the tenant to notify the landlord of their inability to pay. Because you don't have a lease your rights generally are limited, but most states still require a landlord without a lease to still follow some of the eviction processes.

The interesting thing will be how the courts will enforce the back rent if you don't have a lease, and the renter didn't pay during the crisis, and then wants to leave as soon as they can after the crisis protections end.

You always want a lease to make sure both sides understand their obligations, and their rights.

You need to research how your state or maybe even your city is handling these cases. Also investigate what happens if there is no lease. Landlord/tenant law is always a state or local issue. You can also generally find a local free or inexpensive source of help regarding tenant rights.

> Q. Can he legally do that without me giving him permission and in my
>   absence?

In normal circumstances failure to pay will start the eviction process. The court will be the one that will be giving permission. Once they give permission the time and method will be determined. Your presence is not required. In some places the sheriff gets involved. Your lack of lease can complicate your rights because your failure to pay on time can be seen as you terminating the verbal contract.

Answer (score -2):

Legally, he cannot throw your things out. Also you should have some sort of agreement with him regarding rent.

Comment: This is indeed legal in many places. Are you absolutely sure this would not be legal in MA, US?